# How to find where KETTLE HOME is defined

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have a Pentaho installed on my windows machine and am running spoon. I wish to know the file where the KETTLE_HOME is defined. Where can I find this file?

I need to know this info because there is more than one kettle.properties on my computer and I wish to understand which one is being picked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default location for the Pentaho DI home directory is the .kettle directory in your system user's home directory.

> Windows C:\Documents and Settings{user}.kettle

Check your OS environment variables for any defined `KETTLE_HOME`
If it is not defined in your OS environment variables that means it refers to the above default path.

Check [this](https://docs.hitachivantara.com/r/en-us/pentaho-data-integration-and-analytics/10.1.x/mk-95pdia002/manage-the-pentaho-system/manage-the-pentaho-server/advanced-topics/customize-the-pentaho-server/change-the-pdi-home-directory-location) for more details

Comment: Thanks. But I have windows 7 and it does not have 'Documents and Settings'. It has C:\User but I don't see any .kettle in there

Comment: check C:\Users\{username}

Comment: Thank you, I found env variable KETTLE_HOME defined

Comment: how to make it for centos7? define in /etc/profile？